# Having trouble writing rotate function for Tetris game in Python

Tags: python, math, rotation, tetris

I am trying to write a function to rotate the pieces in my Tetris game. I'm using a 20 row by 15 col grid with the 0th and 14th column being boundaries. For the pieces, I am using indexes to spawn them and each piece object has a list of its indexes. I'm attempting to rotate the piece like this:

1. Find the left and right edges of the piece
2. Calculate the origin by adding the left and right edges Xs and Ys and dividing both by 2
3. Subtract the origin from each piece index
4. x,y becomes y, -x
5. Add the origin back

The problem I'm having is that sometimes the origin is is 0.5 or 1.5 etc. I'm solving this by rounding up when I add the origin back. This causes the piece to move to the bottom right side of the grid when only rotating. Can anyone offer advice on how to fix this?

My functions:

```
def update_origin(self):
    self.update_edges()
    centerY = (self.left_edge[1] + self.right_edge[1]) / 2
    centerX = (self.left_edge[0] + self.right_edge[0]) / 2
    self.origin = ((centerX, centerY))
    # print(f'Origin is {self.origin}')
```

```
def update_edges(self):
    self.left_edge = (10, 10)
    self.right_edge = (0, 0)

    for row, col in self.indices:
        if col < self.left_edge[1]:
              self.left_edge = (row, col)
        if col > self.right_edge[1]:
              self.right_edge = (row, col)

        # print(f'Left edge: {self.left_edge} Right Edge: {self.right_edge}')
```

```
def rotate_piece(self):
     new_indices = []

     self.update_origin()

     # print('Subtracting origin from each index')
     for row, col in self.indices:
          new_indices.append((row - self.origin[0], col - self.origin[1]))
          # print(f'{row, col} becomes {row - self.origin[0], col - self.origin[1]}')

     count = 0
     # print('x,y becomes y,-x')
     for row, col in new_indices:
          new_indices[count] = (col, (-row))
          # print(f'{row, col} becomes {col, (-row)}')
          count += 1

     count = 0
     # print('Add origin back')
     for row, col in new_indices:
          new_indices[count] = math.ceil(row + self.origin[0]), math.ceil(col + self.origin[1])
          # print(f'{row, col} becomes {math.ceil(row + self.origin[0]), math.ceil(col + self.origin[1])}')
          count += 1

     # print("Finished rotating")
     return new_indices
```

Sample output:

```
Left edge: (1, 5) Right Edge: (2, 6)
Origin is (1.5, 5.5)
Subtracting origin from each index
(1, 5) becomes (-0.5, -0.5)
(2, 5) becomes (0.5, -0.5)
(2, 6) becomes (0.5, 0.5)
(3, 6) becomes (1.5, 0.5)
x,y becomes y,-x
(-0.5, -0.5) becomes (-0.5, 0.5)
(0.5, -0.5) becomes (-0.5, -0.5)
(0.5, 0.5) becomes (0.5, -0.5)
(1.5, 0.5) becomes (0.5, -1.5)
Add origin back
(-0.5, 0.5) becomes (1, 6)
(-0.5, -0.5) becomes (1, 5)
(0.5, -0.5) becomes (2, 5)
(0.5, -1.5) becomes (2, 4)
Finished rotating
```

Comment: I would rather use lists with predefined offsets for all items in all rotations - and only replace list to get different rotation. OR you could create predefined origin for different rotation.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using one of the piece indexes as an anchor point and using that point as the origin after adding the row and column offset to it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).